# HTTP Error upload ( localhost )

Tags: plugins, uploads, buddypress, http

## HTTP Error ..

I’ve been trying off and on to debug this issue for the last few days and thus far have had no success.

---

The proplem starts with **[BuddyPress](https://buddypress.org/)** plugin ( Profile Avatar Upload Section )

The uploads seems to work fine on the admin dashboard -> media
[image: Media Section Admin Dashboard]

but not on buddypress
when i upload the png/jpg using buddypress it throws a HTTP error and it dose indeed save the img in the UPLOAD folder when i check it

[image: Upload Avatar BuddyPress]

Im not hosting it on a server
Trying and fixing it by **increasing the upload** limit
or
**the memory limit**
i tried it already it didn't work

***Found some say***

> Install php gd on your server it will fix it

, but im using localhost

Also in the DEV Tools this server error occurs

```
http://domainname.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

[image: Google Chrome Dev Tools - Error Code]

---

[image: Ajax Returns 0 Value]

```
wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Ajax File Returning 0

If anybody could please help me try to solve this issue it would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

**Edit** :

Apache Log Error Shows This ::

```
[##########] [php:error] [pid 6888:tid 1828] [client 127.0.0.1:50944] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\domainname\\wp-content\\plugins\\buddypress\\bp-core\\bp-core-avatars.php:936\nStack trace:\n#0 E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\domainname\\wp-content\\plugins\\buddypress\\bp-core\\bp-core-avatars.php(1047): bp_core_avatar_handle_upload(Array, 'bp_members_avat...')\n#1 E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\domainname\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php(292): bp_avatar_ajax_upload('')\n#2 E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\domainname\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)\n#3 E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\domainname\\wp-includes\\plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#4 E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\domainname\\wp-admin\\admin-ajax.php(187): do_action('wp_ajax_bp_avat...')\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\domainname\\wp-content\\plugins\\buddypress\\bp-core\\bp-core-avatars.php on line 936, referer: http://domainname.com/members/admin/profile/change-avatar/
```

Img :

[image: Img of the log file]

Comment: Try enabling debug and check the debug.log file in the wp-content folder https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: so what now ? the WordPress installation in fresh new - and the buddypress plugin is up to date

Comment: Looks like an issue with buddypress code so you should report it to the developers. You might be able to get around it by changing PHP version.

Comment: Got it , thanks